# How to show middle of image in div using css?

Tags: html, css, image, position, css-position

How to show middle of image in div using css ?

https://jsfiddle.net/yn7hubkd/

CSS:

```
.out{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="out">
  <img src="https://redditupvoted.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/waffles-cat.jpg">
</div>
```

I get this output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o59iI.png

But I want to get it like this (centered in x-direction, black square is image and red square is div class out): https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dT5a.png

The output result is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHgCc.png

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This behaviour can simply be achieved by using the image as background. Just set [`background-size: cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) and [`background-position: center;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) to fill the container with the image and position it in the center:

```css
.out {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(https://redditupvoted.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/waffles-cat.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="out"></div>
```

In case that you are forced to use the `<img />` tag, simply add a negative left margin of 50%:

```css
.out {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.out img {
  margin-left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <img src="https://redditupvoted.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/waffles-cat.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I have to use img tag

Comment: Please note: This (second solution) only works because in this particular case the image is exactly twice as wide as the container. Otherwise you need a bit more (see my answer)

Answer (score 12):

You can center it with this CSS rule:

```
.out img {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/456jLdfx/1/

That places it at 50% width of the container and moves it back to the left by 50% of its own width, thereby centering it horizontally.

An additional note: This works for *any* image width, as opposed to `margin-left: -50%;`, which only works in this case because the image is exactly twice as wide as the container: 500px container, 100px image)

Comment: Over 4 years old and still giving me the best solution. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.out {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('https://redditupvoted.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/waffles-cat.jpg') center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add This in your CSS

Please Find your updated Fiddle below.

```css
.out img{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 90%;
  display: block;
}
```

[Your Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yn7hubkd/3/)

Expalnation: `margin:0 auto;` adjust the block level element margin top and bottom to 0 and left and right auto (i.e it will calculate automatically relative to parent.)